# Random matrix with invertible submatrices

Tags: probability, matrices

Given a random $n\times t$ matrix (say over a finite field of cardinality $p$), what is the probability that all of its $t \times t$ submatrices are invertible?

I was computing something with $n\times t$ Vandermonde matrices, which are known to have all their $t \times t$ submatrices invertible, and wondered if this property was true for random matrices too.

Is this true, are there some bounds on the density of such matrices?